# Travelling Salesman Problem Constraint Representation

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I read a couple of articles and sample code about how to solve TSP with Genetic Algorithms and Ant Colony Optimization etc. But everything I found didn't include time (window) constraints, eg. "I have to be at customer x before 12am)" and assumed symmetry.

Can somebody point me into the direction of some sample code or articles that explain how I can add constraints to TSP and how I can represent those in code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Professor Reinelt at university of heidelburg in germany is one of the leading experts for the TSP. He has a collection of papers on the various variants of the TSP.

see http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/

I think your variant is called Vehicle Routing Problem with Time Windows. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem )

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look on what the state-of-the-art on Domain Independent Planning can do for you: http://ipc.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/